# Angular Material : Why md-select when used with ng-model-options triggers the ng-change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a use case wherein I need to use a md-select and provide options from a array. The selected value is saved and fetched from the database. In case, the database has no value stored it returns null.

Now if the value from database is null, I need to set the 4th value of array (i.e Default). So I have the following logic:

```
$scope.MR=  $scope.data.MR !== null  ? $scope.data.MR : $scope.MRList[3];
```

and my template is :

```
<md-input-container class="flex flex-sm-100 TS_action_dropdown md-input-has-value">
                <md-select ng-model="MR" ng-change="updateManualRating(target, MR)" class="new_delta_select" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.name'}">
                    <md-option ng-value="t" ng-repeat="t in MRList track by $index">{{t.name}}</md-option>
                </md-select>
            </md-input-container>
```

As per Angular docs https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect, we need to use ng-model-options to set a pre-defined value, that is matched against the option list. I have done the same, however, after this whole implementation, my ng-change function (written on change of md-select) gets triggered automatically while page loading.

As per Angular docs, this is triggered explicitly on user manual change. I believe too that's how it works. But I am confused, why is it happening. Does Angular material somewhere plays with $viewController and triggers a similar effect?

Or is this a bug or known issue. If yes, How it can be avoided or worked around?